# Protractor, Javascript: How to kill all existing browsers

Tags: protractor, kill, kill-process

I am writing an application for end to end testing using Protractor for an angular 2 application.

Before starting my application I would like to close all browsers that may be running on my machine. e.g. when I am running my test in chrome, I want to close all chrome processes/instances before my test starts.

So, looking for something that I may call in beforeLaunch method of protractor config. (please let me know if there is a better place to call it with the answer of how to do it)